# Typo3 6.2 & Introduction Package - Best Workflow

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I installed the new Typo3 with the Introduction package. It looks great and feature accessability for the less compiler is great!

I am not new to Typo3 though I have a couple of questions about the best workflow.

- Do you use the TS Editor or do you store your own TS in files as well?
- How do you deal with own CSS? Append a new file? If yes, where.
- As I see the introdction package and the ads for "make your own" I couldn't find any documentation how to compile your own package out of a current installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually provide my basic stuff in an extension and I try to have nothing stored in the database, e.g. in template records created from the backend, but everything in files. This way you can add everything to your git ord SVN or whatever versioning you are using.

This includes:

- TypoScript
- HTML / Fluid Templates
- CSS
- JavaScript
- Icons and Images

You add your own CSS files by including the via TypoScript:

```
page.includeCSS.myCustomFile = EXT:my_package/Resources/Public/Css/MyCustomFile.css
```

This folder structure follows the flow / extbase template for extensions in which every kind of resource is stored either in /Resources/Private (mostly templates and language files) or /Resources/Public for resources that need to be publicly accessible (CSS, JS, Images,...). If you follow this folder structure, your configuration is stored in /Configuration/TypoScript.

I haven't seen it yet by myself, but I guess the introduction distribution is an extension as well and as such located in typo3conf/ext/